# Warning NU1701: package build for Core2.0 is being restored with .NET4.6.1 in a .NETCore2.0 app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have build my own nuget package containing a dll build for the .NETCore2.0 framework.

[image: See screen shot of the project properties]

```
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
      <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
      <Authors>xxx</Authors>
      <Company>xxx</Company>
      <Product>xxx</Product>
      <AssemblyName>App.Model.Master.Contract</AssemblyName>
      <RootNamespace>App.V4.Model.Master.Contract</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

I am now trying to import this nuget in another project (MVC dotnetcore 2.0), and I am getting this error:

> Package 'App.Model.Master.Contract 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

[image]

Those both project are using .NET Core 2.0. At no point I am using the classical .NET Framework 4.6.1. Why does it attempt to restore this package using this version of the .NET Framework?

Obviously I am missing something, but I am very confused on what is triggering this error.

Comment: That's not an error, its a warning. It compiles and runs, as long as the package in question doesn't use any APIs unavailable on netstandard 2.0. Basically it tells you, the library you reference is not compiled for `netstandard2.0` so it may or may not work in your case, depending on the API which the library uses. Validate its okay with the .NET Portability Analyzer. Or ask the authors to provide an `netstandard1.x` or `netstandard2.0` version of it

Comment: @Cocotte Dodue did you at some point have a package with the same name that targeted .NET Framework? use `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` to  clear the cache and reinstall the project. unzip (rename in .zip) the nuget package to check if the dll file is in a `lib\netcoreapp2.0` subfolder. Btw, you'll want to target `netstandard2.0` for better reusability - esp. for contract definitions.

Comment: @Tseng hit the nail on the head. NU1701 is a pretty well documented error message (https://blog.nuget.org/20170815/Whats-nu-in-NuGet-with-VS2017-15-3.html) and was announced at .NetConf 2017 (I believe).

Comment: @Tseng, The issue is that both the app that is built into a package - I am creating the package myself and have control over bother app - and the app using it are targetting netcore2.0.
Therefore I do not get why, when trying to restore my package built for netcore2.0 for netcore2.0 it is trying to use net4.6.1?
What would be causing this behavior?
I am building a fairly complex system relying heavily on packages, I cannot afford to have version mismatch now as it might trigger issues in the future